# Indeed Job Scraper only for Postings with External Link

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Currently using the below Python scraper to pull Job title, Company, Salary, and Description. Looking for a way to take it one step further by filtering only results where application link is URL to company website, as opposed to the 'Easily Apply' postings that send application through Indeed. Is there a way to do this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def extract(page):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Software%20Engineer&l=Austin%2C%20TX&ts=1630951951455&rq=1&rsIdx=1&fromage=last&newcount=6&vjk=c8f4815c6ecfa793'
    r = requests.get(url, headers) # 200 is OK, 404 is page not found
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

# <span title="API Developer"> API Developer </span>
def transform(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'slider_container')
    for item in divs:
        if item.find(class_ = 'label'):
            continue # need to fix, if finds a job that has a 'new' span before the title span, skips job completely
        title = item.find('span').text.strip()
        company = item.find('span', class_ = "companyName").text.strip()
        description = item.find('div', class_ = "job-snippet").text.strip().replace('\n', '')
        try:
            salary = item.find('span', class_ = "salary-snippet").text.strip()
        except:
            salary = ""
        
        job = {
                'title': title,
                'company': company,
                'salary': salary,
                'description': description
        }
        jobList.append(job)
#        print("Seeking a: "+title+" to join: "+company+" paying: "+salary+". Job description: "+description) 
    return

jobList = []

# go through multiple pages
for i in range(0,100, 10): #0-40 stepping in 10's
    print(f'Getting page, {i}')
    c = extract(0)
    transform(c)

print(len(jobList))

df = pd.DataFrame(jobList)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('jobs.csv')
```

Comment: Can you please post an example link to job posting you want to filter out?

Comment: Sure, in the following link; this is a job posting for a Data Scientist position that users can apply for directly on Indeed (information is filled out on Indeed, sent from Indeed, etc.). Ideally would be looking for scraper to filter out all these results, and only scrape postings where user must go to company website to apply: https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Scientist&l=Charlotte%20NC&ts=1630961089563&pts=1630954701559&rs=1&vjk=d2c84fffcca6ec17&advn=6349925080182673

Answer (score 0):

My approach is as follows-

Find the `href` from the `<a>` tag for each job card on the initial page, and then send a request to each of those links, and grab the external job link (If "Apply on Company Site" button is available) from there.

Code snippet-

```
#function which gets external job links
def get_external_link(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    
    #if Apply On Company Site button is available, fetch the link
    if(soup.find('a',attrs={"referrerpolicy" : "origin"})) is not None:
        external_job_link=soup.find('a',attrs={"referrerpolicy" : "origin"})
        print(external_job_link['href'])

#add this piece of code to transform function
def transform(soup):
    cards=soup.find('div',class_='mosaic-provider-jobcards')
    links=cards.find_all("a", class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("tapItem"))

    #for each job link in the page call get_external_links
    for link in links:
        get_external_link('https://www.indeed.com'+(link['href']))
```

Note- You can also use the page source of the new requests which are being called to fetch the data like title, company, salary, description which you previously used to scrape from the main page.